# Looping an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
  void searchForPopulationChange()
  {
     String goAgain;
     int input;
     int searchCount = 0;
     boolean found = false;

     while(found == false){
        System.out.println ("Enter the Number for Population Change to be found: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();



        for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
        {
           if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
           {
              found = true;
              System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
           } 

        }


     }
  }
```

}

hello!
I am working on a method that will take an users input,
lets say (5000) and search a data file with those corresponding numbers.
and return the corresponding number, and county that it corresponds with.

However, I am able to get this code to run to return the correct value,
but i am unable to get it to run when i enter an "incorrect" value.

Any pointers?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by an "incorrect value"? Out of range number? Decimal? Not even a valid number?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What is happening? You might want to consider posting more of your code so we can run it ourselves.

Comment: It is a huge code, I dont think i can post it all on here.
Basically I want the program to search a data file ( an array)
There is a county with populations next to it.
I want to search this data file by entering a population number.
The program will then return the corresponding "county" that has that population.

Comment: What i want to happen when i enter an invalid number,
is for the code to loop at and tell the user "Error" and to "re enter" a correct population #

Comment: Did you try testing `found` and producing your error message if that was false?  (Also, of course, you should `break` when the answer is found, to short-circuit the inner loop, or incorporate `found` in your `for` test.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear, but I assume you want something to handle if the input is incorrect (not an integer)? Use `hasNextInt` so you will only capture integers.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    scanner.nextLine();
}
int num = scanner.nextInt();
```

This will keep looping the input until it is a valid integer. You can include a message in the loop reminding the user to input a correct number.

If you want something to display if your number has no match inside of the array, simply add code after your `for` block, if `found == false`. For example:

```
for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
    {
       if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
       {
          found = true;
          System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
       } 

    }
if (found == false) {
     System.out.println("Error, No records found!");
}
```

Since found is still false, your `while` loop kicks in and prints your line requesting for input again.

EDIT: Since you seem to have problem adding these two concepts to your code, here's the whole function:

```
void searchForPopulationChange() {
 String goAgain;
 int input;
 int searchCount = 0;
 boolean found = false;

 while(found == false){
    System.out.println ("Enter the Number for Population Change to be found: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
      scanner.nextLine();
      }
    input = scanner.nextInt();

    for (searchCount = 0; searchCount < populationChange.length; searchCount++)
    {
       if (populationChange[searchCount] == input)
       {
          found = true;
          System.out.print(""+countyNames[searchCount]+" County / City with a population of "+populationChange[searchCount]+" individuals\n");
       } 

    }

    if (found == false) {
       System.out.println("Error, No records found!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would i be placing this?

Comment: The input is inccorect if it is not a valid matchig number inside of the array.

Comment: After `System.out.println ("Enter the Number for Population Change to be found: ");`. Just change your input `input = scan.nextInt();` to utilize the scanner.

Comment: Im sorry, i am still not following this?
so i am changing my 
while (found == false) into while (!scanner.hasNextInt()){
scanner.nextLine();
?

Comment: +1 for the technic, @user2517185: after the for-loop check `if(!found)` (means *found* still false), if it was false, it means that no match was found.

Comment: Yes, The line does print,
but the program no longer searches the array again. It just keeps returning "no records found" even if i enter a correct number.

Comment: I just edited it for both types of incorrect entries (no match or not an integer). You place the scanner check at the same area as your input. Wait, is this your own code? You seem to not show much understanding of it if you think `while (found == false)` needs to be replaced, since it's the loop that keeps the input going if an integer with no match in the array is found.

Comment: It is my own code,
Ive been stuck on this method for a while now.
I've tried using a standard loop with out the boolean true false, but still i canot get the output to correctly correspond the matching population after an "invalid input".

Comment: Hmm, I really don't see a problem with this block of code. As it is, when an integer without an array match is placed, `found` will still be false, and the loop will repeat. (Note that you should not remove that `while (found == false)` loop since it's the one that repeats the whole thing.)

Comment: @MarkM 
if (found == false) {
     System.out.println("Error, No records found!");
}
As you said outside the for loop did wonders!
Such a simple thing.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem! For future reference, if you think an answer solves your problems, just click the check mark at the top left of it. It helps people searching for answers.